# Can one of my POV characters have the last name Thibodaux and get published?

Tags: publishing, word-choice, naming

I live in Louisiana, and names with french origins are very common here. So we all know how they're pronounced.

I'm worried that a publisher will want me to change the name as it may not be so obvious to some people how to pronounce Thibodaux (tih•buh•doe). I don't want to have to change the name after I write the whole book.

Would this be a problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this would be a problem, personally.

If you *do* find that your beta readers are struggling to pronounce "Thibodaux", or a publisher advises that the name may be an issue, a simple solution would be to include a sequence in the book where another character pronounces it wrong and Thibodaux corrects them.

As an example, *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* includes a sequence where Hermione tries to teach Viktor Krum how to pronounce her first name. JK Rowling [later confirmed](https://www.insider.com/harry-potter-jk-rowling-confirmed-fan-theory-pronouncing-hermione-2018-9) that she included that scene because she found that a lot of fans were pronouncing "Hermione" wrong.